# When my app starts a foreground service, is the service in foreground if user has turned off notification permission in settings?

Tags: java, android, notifications, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

In Android system, when my app starts a foreground service, is the service really a foreground service, if user has turned off the notification permission in the settings ?

I am afraid that without a notification, it is a background service in fact, and can't be guaranteed to be finished.

I do such work in my service's onStartCommand function:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "myId")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.all_downloads_icon)
                .setContentTitle("my title")
                .setContentText("you have started a notificaiton")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(110,notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.
I use adb shell to see the service information, it is still a foreground service. And thanks for the question edit suggestion.

```
adb shell
activity services DownloadService(your service's class name)
```

> isForeground=true foregroundId=110
>   foregroundNoti=Notification(channel=myId pri=0 contentView=null
>   vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000
>   vis=PRIVATE)
>           createTime=-2s764ms startingBgTimeout=--
>           lastActivity=-1s772ms restartTime=-2s763ms createdFromFg=true
>           startRequested=true delayedStop=false stopIfKilled=false callStart=true lastStartId=5